# Prioritising Publishes with the Publishing service

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

We are using Sitecore 10.3 with the Publishing Service and have an automated publishing Job that runs every hour to publish some imported content from a 3rd party system. This often means that general content editor publishing is sometimes blocked for a while.

We are using this method currently and need to publish quite a lot of items from a bucket each time:

```
PublishManager.PublishItem()
```

We need the automated Job to run regularly still and it sometimes take 20 minutes or more to complete.

**Ideally we'd like to either:**

1. Allow content editors to prioritise their publishing tasks over these automated ones in the queue. I can't see any documented way of doing this though.
2. Have a secondary Publishing Service which can be used to just handle these automated publishing Jobs. I saw this about high availability but that seems to be more about load balancing the Publishing Service: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0993639
3. Allow pausing of an automated job for a short period of time by Admins only.

Other ideas are welcome.